# SwiftUI: Error in dragging logic or is this a bug?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios-simulator, swiftui

SwiftUI is in beta, so maybe this is a bug, but I've seen something like this working in others YouTube videos so perhaps it's not, the test is pretty simple. I'm creating a circle I can drag around on horizontally.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var location = CGPoint.zero
    var body: some View {
        return Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10)
                    .onChanged { value in
                        print("value.location")
                        print(value.location)
                        self.location = CGPoint(
                            x: value.location.x,
                            y: 0)
                }
        )
            .offset(x: self.location.x, y: self.location.y)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

This results in the behavior:

[image: iphone capture]

As far as I can tell, the `value.location` value in the `DragGesture` `onChanged` callback shouldn't be fluctuating between numbers like this. Looking at the logs the numbers are all over the place. Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens when you set `minimumDistance` to `0`?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth roughly the same thing, though perhaps the jumps are a little less gigantic: https://imgur.com/a/qp8l0dl

Comment: What's your code in `ContentView` (or similar, where you call `TestView()`)?

Comment: `TestView` is my `ContentView`. I switch out what view is loaded as the root view in `SceneDelegate` to whatever test component I'm playing around with. Shouldn't make a difference, as I see the same thing if I copy paste this code into a brand new SwiftUI project. In hindsight I should've just done that so I didn't confuse folks with `TestView`.

Comment: I edited the above code. Made a brand new project and just overwrote `Text("Hello world")` to what's now there, just to make it cleaner. Same result. Thanks for calling that out to remove red herrings.

Comment: You shouldn't add a drag gesture on the circle itself. Or at least, change it's `coordinateSpace` property.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`DragGesture`'s default `CoordinateSpace` is `.local`, which is the coordinate space inside your `Circle`. What happens when you move the `Circle`? Since your finger doesn't move, the location of your finger in the `Circle`'s geometry suddenly changes, which causes the `Circle` to move again. Repeat ad nauseum.

Try using `CoordinateSpace.global`:

```
DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10, coordinateSpace: .global)
```

You'll probably also want to use `value.translation` instead of `value.location` to avoid the initial jump when you put your finger down.